What will be the tension (due to itself) on charged string connected end to end?
I was wondering this that let suppose there's a light string (neglect it's mass) having a charge $+Q$ uniformly distributed, then in equilibrium condition it will be in shape of a ring with radius R so what will be the tension on that string due to itself. I'm saying due to itself because I know if we put a +q at the centre the increment in tension will be /2π² but what will be the tension due to it self?

